# Smooth approximation of ramp function

Tags: functions, approximation

I would like to build a function approaching a [ramp function](https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Rampe_(fonction)) with some parameters defining:

- the activation threshold
- the linear slope
- the 'distance' to the discontinuity, i.e how close we are from the ramp function.

I have started to work on this by combining rational and exponential functions, but I have trouble having isolating the very parameters that control all of this...

Comment: i get linear slope and distance, but what is activation threshold? is it the minimum value?

Comment: It is the value for which the the function starts to increase. But it just results in translating the function along x, so there was no point to bring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

As explained in this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358563)
one of the simplest approximations to the ramp function (which is the integral of the Heaviside step) is
the following
$$
R(x) = {x \over 2}\left( {1 + {x \over {\sqrt {x^{\,2}  + \varepsilon ^{\,2} } }}} \right)\quad \left| {\;\varepsilon  <  < 1} \right.
$$

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for the late response. I recently came across this post and as it so happens, I have been experimenting with such functions recently and figured I would add my two-cents.

For my current research, I needed a smooth(ish) approximation to the Heaviside step function defined on a compact interval. I really wanted to use a similar approach to the one discussed in chapter 13 of the book "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Loring W. Tu. This approach uses the function $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}e^{-\frac{1}{x}},&x>0,\\0,&x\le0\end{array}\right.$$ to construct a $C^\infty$ bump function. When I tried implementing this numerically I ran into some problems due to the very fast nature of how this function approaches $0$ (overflow errors, division by zero, etc. ).

This led me to an approach that is extremely similar to that used in the book but instead of using the function $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$, I needed to find a function with the same basic ''shape'' and behavior as the exponential but which was simpler to compute and used only addition/subtraction, multiplication/division (and was perhaps not $C^\infty$ but just $C^1$ or $C^2$). I thought for a while and finally decided to use the function

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1-\frac{1}{1+x^p},&x>0,\\0,&x\le0\end{array}\right.$$ where $p$ is a positive integer greater than or equal to 2.

To construct the Heaviside step function approximation from this you can simply follow a slightly altered version of the procedure in the book by Tu

Define $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}$ and let $\epsilon$ be the desired width of the smoothed interval around the corner point (in the plots below I use $\epsilon=.1$)

The approximation to the Heaviside-step function is then given by $$H_\epsilon(x)=g\left(\frac{x-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\epsilon}\right)$$

Here is a comparison what Tu's Heaviside step function (red) and my Heaviside step function (purple) approximation look like for $p=2$
[image]

They look very similar and get sharper as you increase the value of $p$. As an added benefit, the function $f$ gains more degrees of smoothness as $p$ is increased.

When I apply this approximation to your desired function $x H(x)$ for $\epsilon=.1$ and $p=4$ the result is visually indistinguishable from the desired result.
[image]

I hope this helps you out! Please let me know if you have any questions regarding my approach